# blank page after send

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli

I tried figured out how I can get the if empty() for different field input also if captcha is empty or wrong

this is the page of comments.php

```
    <div class="box">
        <ul>
            <?php 
                $result = $com->index();
                while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             ?>
            <li><b><?php echo $data['name']; ?></b>  -  
            <?php echo date('M d, Y', strtotime($data['comment_time'])); ?> - 
        <span class="rating"><?=str_repeat('&#9733;', $data['rating'])?></span><br>  
            <?php echo $data['comment'] ?></li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div><br>
    <center>
        <?php 
            if (isset($_GET['msg'])) {
                $msg = $_GET['msg'];
                echo "<span style='font-size:18px'>".$msg."</span>";
            }
         ?>
    
    <div>
        <form action="post_comment.php" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Rating:</td>
                <td><ul class="rate-area">
  <input type="radio" id="5-star" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="5-star" title="Amazing">5 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="4-star" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="4-star" title="Good">4 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="3-star" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="3-star" title="Average">3 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="2-star" name="rating" value="2" /><label for="2-star" title="Not Good">2 stars</label>
  <input type="radio" id="1-star" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="1-star" title="Bad">1 star</label>
</ul></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Your Name:<span style='color:red;font-size:20px'>*</span></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Please enter your name"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Comment:<span style='color:red;font-size:20px'>*</span></td>
                <td>
                    <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Please enter your comment"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <img src="captcha.php?rand=<?php echo rand(); ?>" id='captchaimg' > </td>
                <td> <a href='javascript: refreshCaptcha();'><img src="refresh.png" width="25px"></a> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Enter the code above here :
                  <input id="6_letters_code" name="6_letters_code" type="text" class="form-control"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="contact-submit" value="Post"></td>
                <!-- <td><input style="width: 230px;height: 40px;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Post"></td> -->
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </div>
    <center>
 <script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>
function refreshCaptcha()
{
    var img = document.images['captchaimg'];
    img.src = img.src.substring(0,img.src.lastIndexOf("?"))+"?rand="+Math.random()*1000;
}
</script>
```

and this is the post_comments.php

```
<?php 
    include_once 'controllers/Comment.php';
    $com = new Comment();
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $name    = $_POST['name'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        $rating = $_POST['rating'];
        $capctha = $_POST['6_letters_code'];
        
            if(empty($_SESSION['6_letters_code'] ) ||
              strcmp($_SESSION['6_letters_code'], $_POST['6_letters_code']) != 0)
            {
                header('Location: indexcomment.php?msg='.urlencode('The captcha code does not match!'));
            }

        if (empty($name) || empty($comment)) {
                header('Location: indexcomment.php?msg='.urlencode('<span style="color:red;font-size:20px">Field must not be empty !</span>'));
        } else {
            $com->setData($name, $comment, $rating);
            if ($com->create()) {
                header('Location: indexcomment.php?msg='.urlencode('Comment Posting Successfully'));
            }
        }
    }
 ?>
```

this is the Comment.php

```
<?php 
    include_once './database/DB.php';
    class Comment
    {
        private $db;
        private $name;
        private $comment;
        private $rating;
        private $table = "tbl_comments";

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->db = new DB();
        }

        public function setData($name, $comment, $rating)
        {
            $this->name    = $name;
            $this->comment = $comment;
            $this->rating = $rating;
        }

        public function create()
        {
            $query = "INSERT INTO $this->table(name, comment, rating, comment_time) VALUES('$this->name', '$this->comment', '$this->rating', now())";
            $insert_comment = $this->db->insert($query);
            return $insert_comment;
        }

        public function index()
        {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM $this->table ORDER BY id DESC";
            $result = $this->db->select($query);
            return $result;
        }

        public function dateFormat($data)
        {
            date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
            $date = date('M j, Y', time());
            return $date;
        }


    }
 ?>
```

this the DB.php

```
<?php 
    include_once './config/config.php';
    class DB
    {
        private $host   = DB_HOST;
        private $user   = DB_USER;
        private $pass   = DB_PASS;
        private $dbname = DB_NAME;

        public $link;
        public $error;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->connectDB();
        }

        private function connectDB()
        {
            $this->link = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->dbname);
            if (!$this->link) {
                echo "Connection fail".$this->link->connect_error;
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Insert Data
        public function insert($query)
        {
            $insert_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);
            if ($insert_row) {
                return $insert_row;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Select or Read data
        public function select($query)
        {
            $result = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                return $result;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
 ?>
```

and this a config.php

```
<?php 
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASS', '****************');
    define('DB_NAME', 'dbcomment');
 ?>
```

and this is the captcha.php

```
<?php 

session_start();
//Settings: You can customize the captcha here
$image_width = 280;
$image_height = 40;
$characters_on_image = 6;
$font = './fonts/monofont.ttf';

//The characters that can be used in the CAPTCHA code.
//avoid confusing characters (l 1 and i for example)
$possible_letters = '23456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ';
$random_dots = 30;
$random_lines = 20;
$captcha_text_color="0x142864";
$captcha_noice_color = "0x142864";

$code = '';


$i = 0;
while ($i < $characters_on_image) { 
$code .= substr($possible_letters, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible_letters)-1), 1);
$i++;
}


$font_size = $image_height * .75;
$image = @imagecreate($image_width, $image_height);


/* setting the background, text and noise colours here */
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

$arr_text_color = hexrgb($captcha_text_color);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, $arr_text_color['red'], 
        $arr_text_color['green'], $arr_text_color['blue']);

$arr_noice_color = hexrgb($captcha_noice_color);
$image_noise_color = imagecolorallocate($image, $arr_noice_color['red'], 
        $arr_noice_color['green'], $arr_noice_color['blue']);


/* generating the dots randomly in background */
for( $i=0; $i<$random_dots; $i++ ) {
imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$image_width),
 mt_rand(0,$image_height), 2, 3, $image_noise_color);
}


/* generating lines randomly in background of image */
for( $i=0; $i<$random_lines; $i++ ) {
imageline($image, mt_rand(0,$image_width), mt_rand(0,$image_height),
 mt_rand(0,$image_width), mt_rand(0,$image_height), $image_noise_color);
}


/* create a text box and add 6 letters code in it */
$textbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $font, $code); 
$x = ($image_width - $textbox[4])/2;
$y = ($image_height - $textbox[5])/2;
imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $font , $code);


/* Show captcha image in the page html page */
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');// defining the image type to be shown in browser widow
imagejpeg($image);//showing the image
imagedestroy($image);//destroying the image instance
$_SESSION['6_letters_code'] = $code;

function hexrgb ($hexstr)
{
  $int = hexdec($hexstr);

  return array("red" => 0xFF & ($int >> 0x10),
               "green" => 0xFF & ($int >> 0x8),
               "blue" => 0xFF & $int);
}
?>
```

Somehow I don't get this to work. I been trying to get captcha done when is wrong or empty to show the error notice like "Security code is invalid" and I also tried to get when the name or text is empty that it will show error notice "Name should not be empty" or "Text should not be empty"

I have Debian 10, apache with PHP 8 and mysqli

Comment: Does the redirect happen or not? Have you got error reporting enabled or not?

Comment: @ADyson I think my answer shows that the question was closed too hastily

Comment: @David I actually did not close it. I edit the post and asked for review to open.

Comment: @Christian my words above never have been addressed to you ;-)
Your edit makes the question even more unclear concerning the faults I found, but I never checked now if there are more faults perhaps. In my opinion the question was clear before. without reason to close it.

Comment: @David your answer may have turned out to be correct but it was based somewhat on an assumption or good guesswork. There could be multiple other reasons why a blank screen is seen, as my first comment hints at. The OP provided nothing to try and narrow it down, hence why the question is unclear. I agree though that the extra massive code dump and vague "can't get it to work" description does nothing to clarify the situation!

Comment: @ADyson reading code is no guesswork, my guess was about delivered values that all delivered values have been correct. Anyway, I see still more questions closed too fast currently. Till now I still could submit my answers always, I'd regret writing 20-30 min and being unable to submit then.

Comment: You can always vote to re-open them if you disagree with the closure reason

Comment: Anyway a guess is still a guess. You can't be that's the solution (even if it's a logic issue which does need fixing as well). OP hasn't confirmed either way, sadly they've just muddied the waters even further.

Comment: @ADyson yes the change made it harder, but my answer was written before the change. BTW: it's beginner level and likely for learning only. Nevertheless the hint by hanshenrik below my answer might be quite useful.
Beside that: guess or not, closing questions should have a serious reason, which I didn't see. Also there was no comment to add something or to change the question, that's not nice especially for newbies.

Comment: @David Well I commented to ask for clarification...

Comment: Yes thats right, but there wasn't any indication the question would be closed. So if someone shall improve a question the feedback shall be a bit more clear I think, like with link to the help pages and some welcoming words. Simply the Netiquette, however it's called here.

Comment: @David the site doesn't require comments. If the OP doesn't understand about question closure there is a ton and a half of guidance in the help centre and on Meta. And the closure reason is given in the blue box above the question, with links to more help. I asked for clarification, didn't get it, so the question was closed - and not just by me, remember it requires 3 votes. I see it's been re-opened but tbh it's less clear than ever.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `$_SESSION['6_letters_code']` exists, this condition is omitted but afterwards nothing happens:

```
            if(empty($_SESSION['6_letters_code'] ) ||
              strcmp($_SESSION['6_letters_code'], $_POST['6_letters_code']) != 0)
            {
                header('Location: indexcomment.php?msg='.urlencode('The captcha code does not match!'));
            }
```

That means even the details in your code are logical correct, there is a gap in the combination of all the details.

I propose the changes like this (in short removing the last `else` but executing the code without any condition):

```
<?php 
    include_once 'controllers/Comment.php';
    $com = new Comment();
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $name    = $_POST['name'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        $rating = $_POST['rating'];
                
        if (empty($name)) {
            header('Location: indexcomment.php?msg='.urlencode('<span style="color:red;font-size:20px">Name must not be empty !</span>'));
            exit;
        }
        if (empty($comment)) {
            header('Location: indexcomment.php?msg='.urlencode('<span style="color:red;font-size:20px">Comment must not be empty !</span>'));
            exit;
        }
        if(empty($_SESSION['6_letters_code']) ||
            strcmp($_SESSION['6_letters_code'], $_POST['6_letters_code']) != 0) {
            header('Location: indexcomment.php?msg='.urlencode('The captcha code does not match!'));
            exit;
        }
        $com->setData($name, $comment, $rating);
        if ($com->create()) {
            header('Location: indexcomment.php?msg='.urlencode('Comment Posting Successfully'));
            exit;
        }
    }
 ?>
```

I added `exit` after each redirect to be sure that the script is stopped, as the redirect opens a new site / script.

Comment: I still changed the code a bit and removed all the "else" as they are not required and the code had some faults too like `else if { ... }` which is just wrong without condition.

Comment: warning, doing stuff like ```indexcomment.php?msg='.urlencode('<span style="color:red;font-size:20px">Name must not be empty !</span>')``` may be rejected by modern browsers due to a "xss filter", it's also super unsafe because nothing stops hackers from being able to `indexcomment.php?msg=<script>evilJavascript()</script>`  and all of a sudden your website is vulnerable to xss javascript injection.

Comment: if you really want to do that stuff, a quickfix is to just wrap it in base64 to bypass the xss filter, but if you want to do it safely, look into signing the data (usually also followed by encrypting the data, but if it's signed, encrypting it might not be required?) - or just put the messages in $_SESSION if your website uses cookies

Comment: Yes, the security aspect is important in the wild. I expect though that @Christian is still leaning and on beginner level trying some interactive things only. Anyway, it's correct that the script shouldn't be used like that on a public website (including intranets and internet).